# Find part of a string and then search for another part of he string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to be able to search for certain characters in a `NSString` and if the app has found it, I want it to look for another part of the string. The problem is that the code that I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/example.pdf"];

    if ([data rangeOfString:@"http://"].location != NSNotFound) {

        if ([data rangeOfString:@".pdf"].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"Found .pdf");
        } else {
        NSLog(@"Did not find .pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

... doesn't work; it goes straight to the `else` statement instead of the `if` statement. How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me, I compiled and I got the correct result, it printed 'Found .pdf'.

Comment: Well I don't know why it doesn't show up for me, then.

Comment: Why not use `hasPrefix` and `hasSuffix`? Does your kind of string format can be something else?

Answer (score 0):

For some silly reason, it works when I tell it to search a different string.

```
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/example.pdf"];

if ([data rangeOfString:@"http://"].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *dataToSearchRangeOfString = data;
    if ([dataToSearchRangeOfString rangeOfString:@".pdf"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Found .pdf");
    } else {
    NSLog(@"Did not find .pdf");
    }
}
```

If anyone does know how to solve this issue without needing to do this, I will gladly mark down your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code should work,,

but you can Try this alternative;

```
- (BOOL)isPdfUrl:(NSString*)urls {
    NSArray *elements = @[@"http", @"."];
    for (NSString *element in elements) {
        if ([urls rangeOfString:element].location == NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    NSArray *possibleFiles = @[@"pdf"];
    for (NSString *file in possibleFiles) {
        if ([urls rangeOfString:file].location != NSNotFound) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I need the code to be in `- (IBAction)searchButtonTapped:(id)sender` Sorry: I should have mentioned that in question now. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

May be, there are some cyrillic symbols? For example you can check if 'p' is not a russian 'р'.